# Json data to object

Tags: c#, json

Below is my responseFromServer,

```
{"version":3,"status":"ok","response":{"data":[{"address":"1908 Bull Temple Road","category_ids":[29],"category_labels":[["Community and Government","Education","Colleges and Universities"]],"country":"in","email":"principal@bmsce.ac.in","factual_id":"0c8c762c-52df-48d0-9add-1e6ef3f4df0d","fax":"080 2661 4357","hours":{"monday":[["7:00","15:00"]],"tuesday":[["7:00","14:00"]],"wednesday":[["7:00","13:00"]],"thursday":[["7:00","13:00"]],"friday":[["6:00","14:00"]],"saturday":[["7:00","14:00"]],"sunday":[["10:00","13:00"]]},"hours_display":"Mon 7:00-15:00; Tue 7:00-14:00; Wed-Thu 7:00-13:00; Fri 6:00-14:00; Sat 7:00-14:00; Sun 10:00-13:00","latitude":12.94172,"locality":"Bangalore","longitude":77.565889,"name":"BMS College of Engineering","postcode":"560019","region":"Karnataka","tel":"080 2662 2130","website":"http://www.bmsce.ac.in"},{"address":"R V Vidyanikethan Post, Mysore Road","category_ids":[29],"category_labels":[["Community and Government","Education","Colleges and Universities"]],"country":"in","email":"principal@rvce.ac.in","factual_id":"0389cc9b-0368-4ad7-8259-0c6021cd18d0","fax":"080 2860 0337","latitude":12.923694,"locality":"Bangalore","longitude":77.499105,"name":"R V College Of Engineering","postcode":"560059","region":"Karnataka","tel":"080 2860 1700","website":"http://www.rvce.ac.in"},"included_rows":1,"total_row_count":2}}
```

i am getting from the below code

```
            WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("RequestURL");
            // If required by the server, set the credentials.
            request.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
            // Get the response.
            WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
            // Display the status.
            Console.WriteLine(((HttpWebResponse)response).StatusDescription);
            // Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
            Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();
            // Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);
            // Read the content.
            string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();
```

Used:

```
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
        var data = json.response;
        foreach (var album in data)
        {
            var address = album.address;
        }
```

I can't deserialize the response. I want to get the data from the above Json. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Comment: `I can't deserialize the response` Why? What is the problem? exception? unexpected result? You have a problem in deserializing the json but post the code about how you download it.

Comment: I used JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer), but i cant get the data inside the "response":{"data":[{}]} . Can you suggest some way to get the data inside the response

Comment: dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(responseFromServer);
            var data = json.response;
            foreach (var album in data)
            {
                var address = album.address;
            }

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your json.response is not Enumerable. The property data in json.response is, you should use

```
var data = json.response.data as JArray
```